# Why not called On Registered Method in CrossPushNotificationListener in xamarinForms

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, android-notifications

I have a project with xamarin forms that I registered it in fire Base Web site for sending notification ,But On Registered Method not called and so it cant create token for sending notification ...
What Can I do?
thanks

namespace Cross.Droid
{
    class CrossPushNotificationListener : IPushNotificationListener
    {
        public void OnError(string message, DeviceType deviceType)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

```
    public void OnMessage(JObject values, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
    {

        App.MostrarToken(token);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnUnregistered(DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public bool ShouldShowNotification()
    {
        return true;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Without a code example it will be very challenging to understand your problem and to propose a solution.

Comment: hi,I add codes that you can see them , On Registered Method not called when run Project